# Understanding memory type solidity in function's return type

Tags: solidity, memory

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Crud {

    struct Users{
        uint id;
        string name;
    }

    Users[] users; // this is type storage
    uint length = 0;

    function addUser(string memory _name) public{
        users.push(Users(length,_name));
        length++;
    }

    function getUser(uint _index) view public returns(Users memory){
        return users[_index];
    }
}
```

I have this basic code.

In getUser function why is it expecting the return type of Users as memory? It will return users and that is type storage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what will happen here is the function will copy the values from the Users struct from storage to memory before return. I don't believe you can return storage directly from a public view function anyway since it could go to another contract.

Comment: But if that is true then it will always type memory right? And we will never need any other type. ( I am new to this ). In that case, what is the need to define it if it is always the same?

Comment: the return type can be declared as storage in internal functions, which will make them cheaper as the data does not need to be copied